# Android studio: Alert dialog causes crash when called from a menu but not when called from a button. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-alertdialog

I have this method which displays an AlertDialog:

```
public void showTestDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Message")
            .show();
}
```

It was originally much more complicated, with a title, positive and negative buttons, each calling more code, etc. This is as barebones as I could get it and still get the crash.

When I call this from a button press, it works fine...

```
public void testButton(View view) {
    showTestDialog();
}
```

But when I call it from a menu item click, it crashes seconds after displaying...

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.testDialog:
            showTestDialog();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

In my console/log window this is the line that appears with I click on the menu item:

> D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x9fa61c80 (MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView) with handle 0x92d16a80

... and then this is the only line that appears when the virtual device suddenly closes:

> Device emulator-5554disconnected, monitoring stopped.

Here's the crash report window:

[image]

I already had the most up-to-date drivers for my GPU (GTX 1070) but went ahead and re-installed via a fresh download anyway, but no dice.
I've been at this for hours with no luck. What am I doing incorrectly? I am very new to this. Thanks!

Comment: Strange! I did not encounter such problems before. I was wondering what are the memory settings for your emulator? Can you please provide the emulator enough memory and storage so that it can run smoothly? Did you try running your code in a real device? Does it crash there as well?

Comment: @ReazMurshed I am not familiar with how to allocate memory and storage to it. I have also not yet learned how to run on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

Create dialog with static context like
`new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).setMessage("Message").show();` This mContext assign the context in oncreate method.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Define your AlertDialog instance in your onCreate and just show the dialog on the menu button click. You wouldn't need an additional method to show the dialog as well.

Comment: I've tried this as well, but I get the same result. I initialized the alert in the main class, set up all the title, message, and buttons in the onCreate method, then simply told the alert to ".show();" when the menu item is pressed.